# Anime about a woman/alien with telepathy?

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember seeing this scene from an anime as a child, I think it might be from the 80s/90s and I don’t know how deep into the story it is or anything.

There is some sort of laboratory and I think a naked woman in one of those glass liquid chambers, she then breaks out and there’s loads of alarms blaring but she uses telepathic powers to escape the facility pretty easily and she’s very deadpan the whole time. The only other part I remember is she’s walking on the streets naked and is almost hit by a car but she creates some kind of force field without moving a muscle (she just walks through like normal and a force field appears and the car crashes into it).

Answer (score 5):

Could this be [*Elfen Lied*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elfen_Lied)?

The main character has telepathic powers and breaks out of a facility at the start of the series.

**Warning:NSFW (Nudity / Gore)**